# How can i set timer for wheel rotation in cylinder for iCarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, icarousel

I am using iCarousel in my project. So is there a way i can set timer , while i scroll the Cylinder wheel. I need to keep the wheel rotated for 5 seconds.Need the scrolling animation until that.

Comment: have you tried anything in terms of code? then show us that

Comment: have u read the iCarousel's documentation ?? everything is in there pls check carefully ....

Comment: I have read the documentation.I am able to decelerate the by giving the value 1.0  but it does not stop.IS there a way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you read the documentation of [The iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) carefully you will find that there are certain methods which include the time duration it takes for the iCarousel to move from one index to the other, namely -

```
- (void)scrollToItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index duration:(NSTimeInterval)scrollDuration;
```

This method allows you to control how long the carousel takes to scroll to the specified index.

```
- (void)scrollByNumberOfItems:(NSInteger)itemCount duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

This method allows you to scroll the carousel by a fixed distance, measured in carousel item widths. Positive or negative values may be specified for itemCount, depending on the direction you wish to scroll. iCarousel gracefully handles bounds issues, so if you specify a distance greater than the number of items in the carousel, scrolling will either be clamped when it reaches the end of the carousel (if wrapping is disabled) or wrap around seamlessly.

```
- (void)scrollToOffset:(CGFloat)offset duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

This works the same way as scrollToItemAtIndex:, but allows you to scroll to a fractional offset. This may be useful if you wish to achieve a very precise animation effect. Note that if the scrollToItemBoundary property is set to YES, the carousel will automatically scroll to the nearest item index after you call this method. anyway.

```
- (void)scrollByOffset:(CGFloat)offset duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

This works the same way as scrollByNumberOfItems:, but allows you to scroll by a fractional number of items. This may be useful if you wish to achieve a very precise animation effect. Note that if the scrollToItemBoundary property is set to YES, the carousel will automatically scroll to the nearest item index after you call this method anyway.

Please check these methods . Hope they help...

Comment: How can i Add images as an array in each view in the cylinder.